# How do I make JAX-WS endpoint accept SOAP1.2 messages

Tags: soap, spring-boot, wsdl, cxf, jax-ws

I have a Spring Boot based project using CXF to build a SOAP Web Service.

Sending SOAP 1.1 messages (using SOAPUI) works fine, but when I try to send SOAP 1.2 messaged (using the same WSDL of course) I get the message `"A SOAP 1.2 message is not valid when sent to a SOAP 1.1 only endpoint"`.
The message is self explaining, but I can't understand why my endpoint doesn't accept 1.2 messages.

My WSDL contains the correct bindings and namespaces for soap12.

In my spring @Configuration class I added this to the CXF endpoint bean:

```
    endpoint.setBindingConfig(new BindingConfiguration()
    {
        @Override
        public String getBindingId()
        {
            return SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_MTOM_BINDING;
        }
    });
```

That didn't help.
As I became more desperate, I tried both the `@BindingType` and `@SOAPBinding` annotations which of course didn't work, then I tried `SaajSoapMessageFactory` with `SoapVersion.SOAP_12`. Didn't work. I tried `<extension>true</extension><protocol>Xsoap1.2</protocol>` in my `jaxws-maven-plugin`. Failed.

The endpoint is clearly not configured for receiving SOAP 1.2 messages. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out. I needed to set the binding url when implementing the endpoint. For some unapparent reason setting it afterwards did not work.

```
EndpointImpl endpoint = new EndpointImpl(springBus(), statusService(), SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your request you are sending is hitting a SOAP 1.1 endpoint instead of a SOAP 1.2.

If your WSDL was built using top down approach make sure the SOAP Binding for SOAP 1.2 exists in the wsdl. Also the Port (wsdl:port) for SOAP 1.2 must appear under wsdl:service in the wsdl.

If it was built using bottom up approach make sure this annotation @BindingType(value = SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_MTOM_BINDING) is on your SIB when mtom is enabled otherwise use @BindingType(value = javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING).

Then on client wsdl generation using your maven plugin make sure to use `<extension>true</extension>`.

After the above, for example if you are using wsdl with 2 ports in the wsdl:service section as below:

```
    <wsdl:service name="TestService">
        <wsdl:port name="TestPortSoap11" binding="tns:TestPort12Binding">
            <soap:address location="http://127.0.0.1:8081/testSoap11Endpoint"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="TestPortSoap12" binding="tns:TestPort12Binding">
            <soap12:address location="http://127.0.0.1:8081/testSoap12Endpoint"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
```

For you to use soap 1.2 endpoint make sure you get the instance of the service by calling something like:

```
    TestPortType testService = new TestService().getTestPortSoap12();
```

> Please note the text in **bold** "new
>   TestService().get**TestPortSoap12**()" is matching the name of the
>   **SOAP 1.2 port name** in the wsdl.

OR in your configuration of the web service client make sure the endpoint address you are using is pointing to a SOAP 1.2 port and in our case, for example, it's http://127.0.0.1:8081/testSoap12Endpoint not http://127.0.0.1:8081/testSoap11Endpoint.

If these steps fail, kindly share the wsdl snippet (showing wsdl:service section) and your @Configuration web service spring configs.

Comment: That was not my problem. As I said in my original post, I do have the correct bindings and namespaces for SOAP 1.2. I also mentioned using the extension element without success. However, I solved the problem myself. See my answer.